# How to replace the FirstViewController in a TabBar app with another view controller (Kal)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I created an empty iPad TabBar application using XCode 4, *without* storyboards.  I placed that app in a workspace.  I then added the Kal source (obtained from the iPad Juice build)  to the workspace as a separate project.  The initial build was clean.

I then went to the Kal example (NativeKal) and added EventKitDataSource.h and .m, and NativeCalAppDelegate.h and .m. (The image below shows what files are in the example project)

[image]

This is the code from the NativeCalAppDelegate.h file:

[image]

I tried setting the first TabBar UIView controller to "KalViewController" as I would normally do when using Storyboards, but it isn't listed in the drop down list of classes.

The question is: how do I get the NativeCal example view controller to replace FirstViewController in the in my TabBar application?

Comment: My recommendation is to switch to storyboards it is a lot easier to do UITabBarControllers in them.

Comment: I just came from Storyboards with this app... the Kal stuff uses Nibs, storyboard does not, and I don't know how to incorporate .xib files into Storyboard... that's why I decided to try this way.  :-{

Comment: Just create a new storyboard and copy and paste everything into it and then control drag to from a new UITabBarController to the UIViewControllers that you want to be linked to the tab bar it it does the rest for you. Everything else is the same after that.

Comment: Popeye... I'll give it a try and get back to you... what do I do about the Kal controller's .xib file?  i.e. how do I connect it to the UITabBarController?

Comment: In storyboards you can set the first view controller to be loaded so if you need it to be KalController then you can set it when you set up the UITabBarController. I found doing UITabBarControllers in .nib files really hard and couldn't get them to work.

Comment: Popeye... please take your comment and make an "answer" out of it so I can close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments added as Answer.

My recommendation is to switch to storyboards it is a lot easier to do UITabBarControllers in them. You can do this by just creating a new storyboard and copy and paste everything into it and then control drag from the UITabBarController to the UIViewControllers that you want to be linked to the tab bar controller and it does the rest for you, everything else is the same after that. In storyboards you can set the first view controller to be loaded so if you need it to be KalController then you can set it when you set up the UITabBarController. You can also set this in the code. I found that storyboards were a great new feature to xcode, UITabBarCotrollers are a lot easier to do in them then in .nib files I could never get them to work.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: Thank you... I appreciate your time on this one... :D